# sed into csv format

Tags: sed

I have a file of the form

```
VL-8299673,30.000,49.000,1.000,21.901,2630.000,428861.000
VL-8299673,1071.000,570.000,35.000,3963.608,632.000,366563.000
VL-8299673,36.000,867.000,24.000,6523.005,3544.000,176054.000
VL-8299673,5:281185.000
VL-8299673,44.000,372.000,67.000,7029.358,293.000,446448.000
VL-8299673,5:48479.000
VL-8299673,0:2.000,2:7.000,3:80.222,4:1153.000
```

it is supposed to be of the form

```
VL-8299673,1190.000,609.000,28.000,12676.158,1819.000,452813.000
```

but when there are zeros in the file it only shows the column numbers that are nonzero such as

```
VL-8299673,0:2.000,2:7.000,3:80.222,4:1153.000
```

I would like to write a sed command that makes a 7 length row with zeros included such as

```
VL-8299673,2.000,0,7.000,80.222,1153.000,0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why `sed` and not `awk` (or `perl` or `python` or ...)?

Comment: Woaw! Once again someone reinvented the wheel and now craig, you are screwed :) I don't know from where your file comes from, but you'd better change the program generating that crap to make it generate proper csv. Plus, I guess that you won't just keep the csv somewhere forever: you will process it using whatever you want and if "whatever" is not gnuplot or libreoffice calc, you'd better use this whatever directly to parse that broken format. Oh, one last thing: if the guy who wrote the program really wanted to save space, he would just have zipped it or used a binary format (such as HDF5).

Answer (score 2):

Though it could be done with `sed`, it would be a lot more legible with `perl` ;-):

```
perl -lpe '$n=0;s{,(\d+:)?([^,]*)}{if($1ne""){$r=",0"x($1-$n).",$2";
           $n=$1}else{$r=$&};$n++;$r}ge;$_.=",0"x(6-$n)'
```

A possible `sed` solution (not much tested):

```
sed 's/$/%543210@@@@@@@/;:1
  s/^\(\(@*\)[^,]*\),\([0-9]\):\(.*%.*\3.\{6\}\2\(.*\)\)/\5\1\5\4/;t1
  s/^\([^:]*\),/@\1@/;t1
  s/@*\(.*\)%.*/\1@@@@@@@/;s/\(\(@[^@]*\)\{7\}\).*/\1/
  :2
  s/@@/,0@/;t2
  y/@/,/;s/,$//'
```